# Determine the height that has been scrolled from the top

Tags: jquery

My question tells everything. I have already tried the following :-

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height=$(window).scrollTop(); 
    $(div).html(height); 
});
```

You can see it live at http://jsfiddle.net/JdXQA/ . But it is not working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` is a string literal, not a variable in this case, so you need to enclose it with in `''`

```
$('div').html(height);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EMYS4/)

Answer (score 1):

You have typo. Missing `""`:

```
$("div").html(height);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JdXQA/1/)**</kbd>